# Prolog, binary tree

Tags: prolog

I want to find the deepest element of a binary tree, So far the code only works for empty tree or the height is one.

Here is the code
My height function works correctly.

```
deepest(node(L,X,R),X):- height(L,0),height(R,0).
deepest(node(L,_,R),X):- height(L,D1),height(R,D2), D1 > D2,  deepest(L,X).
deepest(node(L,_,R),X):- height(L,D1),height(R,D2), D1 =< D2, deepest(R,X).
```

edit: example

```
?- deepest(node(node(node(leaf,8,leaf),20,leaf),
                      30,
                      node(node(leaf,88,leaf),33,node(leaf,888,leaf))),
                 X).
X = 8 ;
X = 88 ;
X = 888 ;
false.
```

Comment: Can you give an example of query?

Comment: It looks fine to me, at least to get the first result. It may have problems with the backtracking.
What happens if you change the first rule to `deepest(node(leaf,X,leaf),X).`?

Comment: Same, it works fort empty tree and (node(leaf,1,leaf).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the relation `height` (btw there are *not* functions in Prolog), will be useless for the task, because it forgets the essential info required.

```
deepest(T, E) :-
    deepest(T, E, _).

deepest(node(L, X, R), E, D) :-
    deepest(L, EL, DL),
    deepest(R, ER, DR),
    (   DL > DR
    ->  E = EL, D is DL + 1
    ;   (   DL < DR
        ->  E = ER, D is DR + 1
        ;   (   DL > 0  % DL & DR are equals
            ->  E = L, D is DL % deepest is arbitrary here
            ;   E = X, D is 1
            )
        )
    ).
deepest(N, N, 0).
```

**edit** for intended data structure, instead of `deepest(N, N, 0).` I think it's clearer to use

```
deepest(_, _, 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate version which makes use of some basic built-ins, namely `append/3`, `keysort/2`, `reverse/2`, and `maplist/3`:

```
deepest(Tree, N) :-
    deepest(Tree, 0, NL),
    maplist(strip_key, NL, N).

deepest(leaf, _, []). 
deepest(node(L, X, R), D, [DN-N|Res]) :-
    NewD is D + 1,
    deepest(L, NewD, LL), 
    deepest(R, NewD, RL),
    append([D-X|LL], RL, NL),
    keysort(NL, KL),
    reverse(KL, [DN-N|Rem]),
    first_key_run(Rem, DN, Res).

first_key_run([DN-N|Rem], DN, [DN-N|NL]) :-
    !, 
    first_key_run(Rem, DN, NL).
first_key_run(_, _, []).

strip_key(_K-V, V).
```

This version builds up a list of `Depth-Node` items at every node in the tree, performs `keysort/2` to the list which orders them shallowest-first (O(N·log(N)), reverses the order (O(N)), then keeps the first run of equal-deepest nodes (O(N)).

This version also computes *exactly* the number of nodes at equal-deepest depth. For example:

```
?- deepest(node(node(node(leaf,8,leaf),20,leaf),30,node(node(leaf,88,leaf),33,node(leaf,888,leaf))), X).
X = [88, 888, 8].
```